# how to get date from form control

Tags: angular, typescript

html

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="startDate" >
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="endDate" >
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

ts.

```
  searchForm = new FormGroup({
      startDate: new FormControl(),
      endDate: new FormControl(),
    }
  );
```

> i want this date
> ex.
> '2022-12-31'
>
> but this output is
>
> console.log(this.searchForm.value.startDate) Output : 2022-12-31

```
i try startDate = new Date(this.searchForm.value.startDate)
but Output is 1970-01-01T00:00:00
```

Comment: This is the beginning of epoch time. If the user has not selected the date, it will default to that. You can make it `required` so that submit event would be triggered only when user has selected some date.

Answer (score 1):

As a input type date return an string (and is feed by a string) you can use two functions

```
formatDate(date: Date | null): string | null {
  if (date)
     return date.getFullYear()+'-'+
            ('00'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+
            ('00'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)
  return null
}
parseDate(value: string | null): Date | null {
  if (value)
     return new Date(value)
  return null;
}
```

Then, instead use formControl we can use ngModel and ngModelChange

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" 
          [ngModel]="formatDate(searchForm.get('startDate').value)"
          (ngModelChange)="searchForm.get('startDate').setValue(parseDate($event))"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
 >
 ...
</form>
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mje8he?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You get YYYY-MM-DD string ***or empty string*** from the input with type date. See [<input type="date">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

For the empty string it will default to January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (the ECMAScript epoch). See [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

```
const dateEmpty = new Date(“”);
const dateFromString = new Date(“2022-12-31”);
   
console.log(dateEmpty);
console.log(dateFromString);
```

How to handle the case when user hasn’t put a date is up to you. For example you could force input via validation `Validators.required` and prevent user from submitting form until they have done so or alternatively you could map to a `Date | null` TypeScript type where `null` signifies not provided.